# Woocommerce New Customer Email Based On User Role

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, dokan

I'm working on a multivendor marketplace. I'm trying to customize the Woocommerce customer_new_account email based on the user role. A vendor should receive a different email than a customer does after sign-up. It doesn't seem impossible to me but I can't find any action to which I could deploy some conditional logic. Can anyone suggest how best to tackle this problem?

Comment: Duplicate: [Customize customer new account mail based on user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441024/customize-customer-new-account-mail-based-on-user-role-in-woocommerce/61443645#61443645)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Customize customer new account mail based on user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61441024/customize-customer-new-account-mail-based-on-user-role-in-woocommerce)